# htaccess change part of REQUEST_URI name if IMAGE not found 404/403

Tags: apache, .htaccess

hi i need help with htaccess and change part of REQUEST_URI

i have a images on alow of folders like this url:

```
https://pic.domain.com/images/111/34%20(Big).jpg
```

only if that image does not exsist on server 404 or 403, i need to change the url to

```
https://pic.domain.com/images/111/34.jpg
```

i need to remove from the `%20(Big)` string and redirect to new url

i have tryied this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/%20(Big)/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

but i dont know what i need to do next.

thanks!

Comment: Next thing to do would obviously be to read the documentation of the tool you want to use. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: i have tryed this RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/%20(Big)/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so many scenarios according to your own requirements , one is like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\.(.+)$ /$1.$3 [R=301,L]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it .

If you want to match wrong request with only `.jpg` extension do this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.jpg$
RewriteRule ^([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\.(.+)$ /$1.$3 [R=301,L]
```

If both `jpg or jpeg` do this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.jpe?g$
RewriteRule ^([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)\.(.+)$ /$1.$3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks but i have tryed ot on htaccess.mwl.be and its not working

Comment: can you add a rule that only rediect if the 404 is a jpg file?

Comment: thanks but now its redirect all images not just 404 images

Comment: it is better to paste the rest of .htaccess

Comment: it seems you should enable those lines 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /images/$1 , get all # out then put my code under them

Comment: hi i know what is the problom .the server return 304 or 404 so i need to look for 404 and 303 for redirect, thanks